# Redireccionar a pagina HOME si el token está activo

Tags: java, angular

Tengo un login que se conecta con el BE para verificar el inicio de sesión y le crea un token. 
Cuestión, cuando abro otra pestaña del buscador donde inicié sesión, me va a la pagina del login, no va al home. Como podría hacer para saber si tengo un token activo para redireccionarlo? 
La estructura es así:
Login service se conecta con el backend.
En el backend, login controller se contecta con login service, el cual le da el token. 
Estoy usando JWT.
Cualquier consejo o ayuda me serviría
gracias!

Comment: puedes compartir tu codigo del java para ver tu implementacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que tu componente principal se llame `MainViewComponent`. Este `MainViewComponent` es el que se encargará de mostrar el `<router-outlet>`; es decir, cualquier ruta en tu *webapp* va a instanciar este componente.

Suponiendo que una vez iniciada la sesión, el *token* se va a guardar en el `localStorage` del *browser* o en el `sessionStorage` (dependiendo de tus necesidades); puedes saber si el usuario ha iniciado sesión o no.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  // ...

  public isAuthenticated = (): boolean => {
    // Aquí aplicas la key que quieras darle
    // Y si buiscarás en localStorage o sessionStorage
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Retornamos si el token existe
    return !!token;
  }
}
```

En tu `MainViewComponent`, entonces, inyectas tanto este `AuthenticationToken` como un `Router` que permitirá redireccionar a cualquier ruta de tu aplicación.

```
// @Component...
export class MainViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private service: AuthenticationService) { }

  // Lo hacemos en el ngOnInit
  // para que no haya renderizado nada de la pagina
  // en caso de que el usuario no esté autenticado
  ngOnInit() {
    // Comprobamos que el usuario haya iniciado sesión
    if (!this.service.isAuthenticated()) {
      // En caso que no esté autenticado
      // navegamos a la ruta de login
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }

    // En caso que sí esté autenticado
    // la webapp cargará el componente
    // de la ruta ingresada de forma normal
  }
}
```

Por último, sólo debes preocuparte de añadir el *token* en el `localStorage` una vez el usuario haya iniciado sesión para prevenir redirecciones a la ruta `login`.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias. Te quiero mucho